# Should one use the term "adjective agreement" or "adjectival agreement"?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, attributive-nouns

Is it better to use the term *adjective agreement* (noun noun) or *adjectival agreement* (adjective noun)?

By contrast, when talking of subject-verb agreement, I'm not aware of an adjectival term like subjective-verbal agreement or subject-verbal agreement.

Comment: Better by what standard? There _isn't_ an objective standard. You choose your authority (which might be your own gut feeling) and follow what that authority says.

Comment: If you have a well-trained gut, you may even be able to share feelings. Lacking any example of the phenomenon that's being discussed, I would not comment on appropriate terminology. Data comes **first**, terminology comes later.

Comment: An example of the phenomenon is "Italian adjectival agreement". I just want to know if people have an opinion or feeling about either one. I tend to favor adjectival, but I always get the sense (perhaps erroneously) that it is archaic.

Answer (score 0):

"Subjective" and "verbal" in association with "agreement" would convey ambiguity, wouldn't they ?

Comment: Aluna, as this appears to be a question about the question, perhaps delete it and ask in a comment.